# The width/height rate of the photos from UIImagePickerController on iPhone

Tags: iphone, size, uiimagepickercontroller

I thought the iphone width/height size is 320 * 480. But the photo taken from UIImagePickerController is about 320 * 430.

Not sure whether I missed anything.

```
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;

[window addSubview: picker.view];
```

Any advices? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a navigation bar?

Comment: no, I am not using navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the picture size rate is 640 * 480. Assume the shorter line is width, I used :

h = 320.0f * heightFromImage / heightFromWidth;

heightFromImage is 640 and heightFromWidth = 480.

The saved image looks correct.